# Convert fields to timestamp for comparison

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a Postres database and want to compare two timestamp fields.

Basic query:

```
select t1.valu1, t1.valu2 from table1 as t1 where t1.valu1 == t1.valu2
```

With timestamp comparison:

```
select t1.valu1, t1.valu2 from table1 as t1
where EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE  t1.valu1 )
  ==  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE  t1.valu2 )
```

Sample values for `valu1`:
 `'14:50:15'`, `'10:50:15'`

`valu2`:
`'11:10:15'`,  `'17:50:15'`

I want to convert `valu1` and `valu2` to timestamps and compare them afterwards.

```
// syntax of extract
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '20:38:18');
```

I get an error in the following format:

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE  t1.valu2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample values are text representations for [**`time`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) not `timestamp`:

```
'14:50:15', '10:50:15', '11:10:15', '17:50:15'
```

Assuming `text` as source type according to later comment.

It would make sense to cast them to time to eliminate insignificant white space or leading 0 from the comparison. But for a simple cast, it has to be a valid time format:

```
SELECT valu1, valu2
FROM   table1
WHERE  valu1::time = valu2::time
```

If you'd really want to compare "as timestamps", you'd need to use [`to_timestamp()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) with a matching format pattern:

```
SELECT valu1, valu2
FROM   table1
WHERE  to_timestamp(valu1, 'HH24:MI:SS')
     = to_timestamp(valu2, 'HH24:MI:SS');
```

But this hardly makes any sense ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to give, at least, a day, e.g.:

```
select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM '2010-07-05 20:38:18'::timestamptz);
```

gives

```
 date_part
------------
 1278358698
```

Comment: but in the pgsql site i had seen the syntax which i used, but in the example its given in a quotes and mine is a field value. So I think the error is there? But i dont know how to convert

Comment: and i need to use in where clause

Comment: @cod As to the first comment, be more clear; as to the second, it's exactly the same in the where clause. But the real question is – why do you want to compare the epochs? Why not the timestamptz values themselves?

Comment: OK, if your times are just strings like hour:minute:seconds, why don't you compare the string themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast them:

```
select dateintext1::timestamp - dateintext2::timestamp from ...
```

Note that you can cast to time, date, timestamp, etc.  As long as the format in the field is correct.

Far better to convert the text fields to date, time, or timestamp fields.

```
alter table abc alter column texttime type timestamp using (texttime::timestamp);
```